# Is it possible to use interpolation in MATLAB without resizing an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, interpolation

I have an image in which some pixels were changed to zero intentionally. Now I want to make a bilinear interpolation to find out new pixel values using the neighborhood as the bilinear interpolation does. However, I don't want to resize the image (MATLAB can do bilinear interpolation only with resize function).

Is it possible to make a bilinear interpolation in MATLAB without resizing? I read that a convolution with the bilinear kernel would solve this. Do you know which kernel is this? is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: You might find [inplant_nans](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551-inpaint-nans) useful. Instead of 0s make these pixels NaN, and you should be able to use the function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. However, I am implementing an image processing approach that asks me to use bicubic or bilinear interpolation. Does the code you suggested perform these interpolation techniques?

Comment: I don't think it has those specific methods unfortunately, I just use it myself a lot for image interpolations and it is quite good. If you have that specific requirement you might want to look somewhere else.

Comment: Please see this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12429348/7906900). In short, you can use inplant_nans ([methods overview](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/4551/versions/2/previews/Inpaint_nans/inpaint_nans.m/index.html?access_key=) )or TriScatteredInterp/scatteredInterpolant, both support linear interpolation and do not support cubic.

Comment: What does it mean "without resizing"?  what do you want to interpolate, if you dont create new values? This needs a bit more explanation. interp2 does various types of interpolation

Comment: @AnderBiguri They want to replace the 0 values with the values found by interpolating their neighbors.

Comment: @beaker right, but that is not really interpolation nor you can just use "bilinear" for this, right? what are the neighbours? You can use just 4 points for bilinear. What if the zero is in a corner? etc etc

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use one of the options supported by [`griddata`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html#input_argument_d0e364882):

> ```
> griddata(..., METHOD) where METHOD is one of
>     'nearest'   - Nearest neighbor interpolation
>     'linear'    - Linear interpolation (default)
>     'natural'   - Natural neighbor interpolation
>     'cubic'     - Cubic interpolation (2D only)
>     'v4'        - MATLAB 4 griddata method (2D only)
> defines the interpolation method. The 'nearest' and 'linear' methods 
> have discontinuities in the zero-th and first derivatives respectively, 
> while the 'cubic' and 'v4' methods produce smooth surfaces.  All the 
> methods except 'v4' are based on a Delaunay triangulation of the data.
> ```

**Example**

```
% create sample data
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:10, 1:10);
Z_original = X.*Y;

% remove a data point
Z_distorted = Z_original;
Z_distorted(5, 5) = nan;

% reconstruct
valid = ~isnan(Z_distorted);
Z_reconstructed = Z_distorted;
Z_reconstructed(~valid) = griddata(X(valid),Y(valid),Z_distorted(valid),X(~valid),Y(~valid));

% plot the result
figure
surface(Z_original);

figure
surface(Z_distorted);

figure
surface(Z_reconstructed);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: In your example, you have matrices X, Y, and Z, and Z is formed by X and Y. I have only one matrix Z with 1500x1500x3 dimensions. How can I split my Z matrix in matrices X and Y as in your example?

Comment: `[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:1500, 1:1500)`. Note that X, Y are the coordinates for each point where you evaluated Z. You probably want to interpolate the third dimension independently.